# change a portion of a line after a regexp

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

How do I change a portion of a line after a regexp?

I have a file where I need to modify the line (on the fly) with `name =` in it but only the one that comes after line with `cluster {` in it. The file is like this:

```
cluster {
  name = "Some _ Name"
  owner = "Cavendish Laboratory"
  .....
  .....
}
module {
    name = "core_metrics"
}
service {
    name = "ssh_check"
}
......
......
```

I can perform this two task separately, like:

```
sed -n '/cluster\ {/{n;p;}'               # next line after cluster
sed -ic "/name\ =\ /{s:OLD:NEW:g}"        # replace OLD with NEW on the fly
```

But how do I combine that two to get the end result like: ?

```
cluster {
  name = "Worker Nodes"
  owner = "Cavendish Laboratory"
  .....
  .....
}
```

How do I do that? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
old="Some _ Name" new="Worker Nodes"

sed '/cluster {/,/}/s/name = "'"$old"'"/name = "'"$new"'"/' file
cluster {
  name = "Worker Nodes"
  owner = "Cavendish Laboratory"
  .....
  .....
}
module {
    name = "core_metrics"
}
    service {
    name = "ssh_check"
}
......
......
```

- Focus on lines between `cluster {` and `}`. `/cluster {/,/}/`
- Substitute `new` for `old` `s/name = "'"$old"'"/name = "'"$new"'"/`

Comment: fantastic!! that works just fine. Now, how can do the same for a `"what-ever-it-is"` string as oppose to a static value i.e. `Some _ Name` in this case. I tried with `[a-z].*` and didn't work. Cheers!!

Comment: Change the `s` command to `s/name = "[^"]*"/name = "'"$new"'"/`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it "in words":

1) Read each line

2) Whenever a line pattern-matches `cluster {`, set a boolean variable `wasClusterLine = true`

3) On the next line, if `wasClusterLine` is true, then do your `name =` reg-ex replace on the current line

4) set `wasClusterLine = false`, because you only want to do your reg-ex replace on the line immediately after `cluster {` .

Hope that helps!  Here's a perlscript that should do what I've described above.

```
use strict;
my $wasClusterLine = 0;
while(<STDIN>) {
        chomp $_;

        if($wasClusterLine == 1) {
                $_ =~ s/name = .*/name = "Worker Nodes"/g;
        }
        $wasClusterLine = 0;

        if($_ =~ /cluster/) {
                $wasClusterLine = 1;
        }

        print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: that's a very neat solution but I was looking for more like a "one liner". Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ple 'do {$_ =~ s/name = .*/name = "Worker Nodes"/; $flag = 0} if $flag; $flag = 1 if $_ =~ /cluster/' inputfile
```